# Fast way to rebuild and reload opendaylight bundle

Tags: opendaylight

I am developing a bundle for opendaylight. Is there a quick way to just rebuild the bundle without the complete karaf environment?

Thanks in advance!
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebuild the bundle, without anything else, by running Maven in the directory containing your bundle’s POM. If you’re on the command-line:

```
cd your-bundle-directory
mvn compile
```

(or `mvn install` etc. depending on what you want to do exactly).